# Maximum of a trigonometric expression

Tags: trigonometry

Maximize $f(x)=4\sin x+48\sin x\cos x+3\cos x+14\sin^2x$ I broke it in 2 parts but then realized they don't have their maxima at the same points. So I am stuck. This is what I did. I wrote it as $$3\cos x+4\sin x+2\sin x(24\cos x+7\sin x)$$ Now we can maximize the first two terms and the terms inside the bracket.

Comment: Why did you break in two parts ? Could you explain your reasoning ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $ \tan (x) = \frac {3}{4} $, then $ \tan (2x) = \frac {24}{7} $

With $ 48 \sin x \cos x = 24 \sin (2x) $ and $ 14 \sin^2 x = 7 - 7 \cos (2x) $

And consider the Pythagoras Triplets $ (3,4,5), (7,24,25) $

We have

$ f(x) = ( 4 \sin x + 3 \cos x ) + (24 \sin (2x) - 7 \cos (2x) ) + 7 $

Express them in terms of $ R \sin (\theta \pm \alpha ) $, [link for reference](http://www.intmath.com/analytic-trigonometry/6-express-sin-sum-angles.php)

$ \text{max} (f(x)) = 5 + 25 + 7 = 37 $

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=4\sin x+48\sin x\cos x+3\cos x+14\sin^2x$

Step 1: Take derivative and equate it to zero

$f'(x)=4\cos x+48(\cos^x-\sin^2 x)-3\sin x+14(2\sin x\cos x)$

$\implies 4\cos x + 48\cos 2x-3\sin x+14\sin 2x=0$

Step 2: Find the solution to above equation.

Step 3: It will attain a maxima if $f''(x)<0$, that means second derivative of the function.

[Follow this wolfram Alpha link for solutions.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%5Ccos+x+%2B+48%5Ccos+2x-3%5Csin+x%2B14%5Csin+2x%3D0)

Comment: From your solutions(which are not much good looking), you want me to substitute them back to get the answer. Looks like a hell of a task.

Comment: That's how It's done! These are called derivative tests for maxima,minima. [Read these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_derivative_test)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Let $a = \cos x, b = \sin x \Rightarrow f(x,y) = f(a,b) = 4a + 48ab + 3b + 14a^2, a^2+b^2 = 1$.

One way out is to use the Lagrange Multiplier:

$\nabla(f) = \lambda \nabla(g) \to (4+48b+28a, 48a+3) = \lambda(2a,2b)$.

Can you solve for $a,b$ from this?

Comment: I don't know Lagrange multiplier.